# Is it possible to stream an IP camera's video feed to a local media player, e.g., VLC?

Tags: android, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming

There are *a lot* of posts on this topic, and I've done my best to comb through all the ones I can find, but I haven't yet encountered (or may have unintentionally overlooked) how to do so for my particular usage.

First of all, I am trying to accomplish this for streams that are hosted by a mobile application called [Alfred](https://alfred.camera/); I use Android devices, and a Win10 Pro x64 setup to view the streams via their browser-based WebViewer.

I have practically no experience or background knowledge on media streams and how the technology works on the backend, but here is what I've inferred from fumbling around on my own (I am assuming I could be wrong about many, if not all, of these):

- The stream delivery method (terminology?) is WebRTC, and runs off of js scripts
- The authentication token is provided and authenticated through Google account services
- If authentication passes validation, VideoPlayer.js or other such module will fetch the actual video URL and decode; an api is invoked, which retrieves a JSON container
- The actual footage is hosted on a BOSH server(?), and the streaming technology or format is known as JabberXMPP
- The app components, and/or possible the WebViewer, communicate using FirebaseCM
- Facebook seems to offer some sort of feature that is being utilized, but I can't determine what exactly (maybe just ad syndication?)
- I was able to find a manifest of all the API calls, but I am hesitant to post those as I have no idea whether or not that is considered sensitive information or not.

I tried my best, but given my lack of fundamental knowledge on this subject, I am making much too many assumptions and inferences with no guidance or verification whatsoever.  I even decompressed the Android application and spent several hours trying to make sense of the contents.  I'd like to consult the community on the following:

**Primary Objective and Question(s)**

- What is the procedure to configure VLC or similar media player client to view this specific streaming format (assuming it is possible)?

Comment: Is it acceptable to discuss the 2nd bullet (struck-out) in the comments instead?

Comment: Comments are meant for clarifying and improving posts, not for discussing them; so no, it would not be appropriate to have a discussion in the comments. However, you have enough rep to join Chat which is exactly for that purpose.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator thanks for clarification, hadn't realized that at all, will go over and check it out, maybe even post something when I'm done being intimidated lol.  In terms of this post, I believe I've increased its specificity as much as I can...?  Or is there some other reason it's still on hold?

Comment: No worries about learning how the site works. You only need 1 more vote before your post is reopened.